# Existence of certain autormorphism in Normal extensions

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Let $F \subset L$ be and normal extension. If $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ are in $L$ and $p(x) \in F[x]$ are they mininal polynomial, and $\beta_1, \beta_2$ with $g(x) \in F[x]$ his minimal prove that exists $\sigma \in Gal(L,K)$ such that $\sigma(\alpha_1)=\alpha_2$ and $\sigma(\beta_1)=\beta_2$.

First, ($p$ and $g$ roots are distinct) If this roots are equal, the identity map $ id \in Gal(L,K)$ will do. So supose the roots are distinct, then $[L,K]\geq 2$.

I know that if exists, $\sigma$ must take roots of minimal polynomials to another root and since the extension is normal $p,g$ splits over $L$, so the result is easy to see, but my dificult is to see why there must be this autormorphism? why can't $Gal(L,K)= \{id\}$?

Comment: This is really difficult to understand. But it doesn't look right, because you could take $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\beta_1$ but $\beta_2 \ne \beta_1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt yes, there are some extreme cases like that that need to be neglected. Otherwise I think this is fine.

Comment: thanks, this case must indeed be excluded, I already edited the question

Comment: But why can't I choose, for example, $F={\mathbb Q}$, $L={\mathbb Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, $\alpha_1=\alpha_2 = \sqrt{2}$, $\beta_1=1+\sqrt{2}$, $\beta_2=1-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I would say we have to assume the following: $\alpha_1 \neq \alpha_2$, $\beta_1 \neq \beta_2$, $\alpha_1 \neq \beta_1$ and $\alpha_2 \neq \beta_2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt ah, even after neglecting the obvious extreme cases, you are still right. It is not necessary that an automorphism should exist. I will type an answer soon.

Comment: Are you assuming that the fields are finite? Not that it changes the verdict, but it has a significant impact on the counterexamples. Just to make sure [tag:finite-fields] is an appropriate tag for questions involving fields with finitely many elements. There are infinitely many rational numbers, so such fields are excluded. Newbies often add that tag when dealing with field extensions of a finite degree, but that is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear that such a $\sigma$ will exist in general.

Some obvious problematic cases are:

1. $\alpha_1 = \beta_1$ and $\alpha_2 \neq \beta_2$. This is immediately problematic because if $\sigma(\alpha_1) = \alpha_2$, then $\sigma(\beta_1) = \sigma(\alpha_1) = \alpha_2 \neq \beta_2$.
2. $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2$ and $\beta_1 \neq \beta_2$. Consider @DerekHolt's example in the comments. Take $F = \mathbb{Q}$, $L = F(\sqrt{2})$, $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \sqrt{2}$, $\beta_1 = 1 + \sqrt{2}$ and $\beta_2 = 1 - \sqrt{2}$. Obviously if $\sigma(\alpha_1) = \alpha_2$ then $\sigma(\beta_1) = \beta_1 \neq \beta_2$.
3. $\alpha_1 = \beta_2$ and $\alpha_2 = \beta_1$. If $Gal(L/F)$ is cyclic of degree $3$, for instance, then there cannot exist any $\sigma$ satisfying the conditions we seek.

Even neglecting such scenarios, suppose $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta_1,\beta_2$ are all distinct. It is still not necessary that such a $\sigma$ will exist. For example, consider $p(X) = g(X) = Irr(\zeta,\mathbb{Q},X)$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive $7$th root of unity. We know that $Irr(\zeta,\mathbb{Q},X) = 1 + X + X^2 + \dots + X^6$, and the roots of this polynomial are $\zeta^j$ for $j = 1,\dots,6$.

Let $\alpha_1 = \zeta$, $\alpha_2 = \zeta^2$ and $\beta_1 = \zeta^3$, $\beta_2 = \zeta^4$. If $L = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ is the splitting field of $Irr(\zeta,\mathbb{Q},X)$, then there is no $\sigma \in Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ such that $\sigma(\alpha_1) = \alpha_2$ and $\sigma(\beta_1) = \beta_2$. Because, if $\sigma(\zeta) = \zeta^2$, then $\sigma(\zeta^3) = \zeta^6 \neq \zeta^4$.

Perhaps we want that the 4 elements $\alpha_i,\beta_j$ are all distinct, and additionally that $p$ and $g$ are distinct?
But even that doesn't work. Let $F = \mathbb{Q}$. Let $p(X) = X^4 - 2X^2 + 9$ and $g(X) = X^2 - 2$. Let $\alpha_1 = \sqrt{2}+i$, $\alpha_2 = \sqrt{2}-i$ and let $\beta_1 = \sqrt{2}$ and $\beta_2 = -\sqrt{2}$. Let $L$ be a splitting field of $\{p,g\}$. There is no $\sigma \in Gal(L/F)$ such that $\sigma(\alpha_1) = \alpha_2$ and $\sigma(\beta_1) = \beta_2$.

So, the only reasonable answer to the question of whether such a $\sigma \in Gal(L/F)$ exists is that it does not exist except under very special circumstances.

Comment: what if I supose that $p$ and $g$ does't have any irreducible factor in common?

Comment: @EduardoSilva Since $p$ and $g$ are irreducible, this is equivalent to saying that $p$ and $g$ are distinct.

Comment: @EduardoSilva The problem is when the intersection $F(p)\cap F(g)$ of the fields of decomposition of $p$ and $g$ is larger than $F$, which is the same as $p$ not being irreducible in $F(g)$